# Decorating with @tf.function changes if condition output

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to evaluate if my variable a is empty (i.e., has `size == 0`). However when decorating the code with `@tf.function`, the if statement incorrectly evaluates as True, whereras when removing the decorator it evaluates as False. `tf.size(a)` seems to correctly evaluate to 0 in both cases. How to fix this ?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
a=tf.Variable([[]])
@tf.function
def test(a):
    print_op = tf.print(tf.size(a))
    print(tf.size(a))
    if tf.math.not_equal(tf.size(a),0):
        print('fail')
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
        return None
test(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit of a head-scratcher but, once we understand that `tf.function` is mapping python ops & control flow to a tf graph whereas the bare function is just executing eagerly, we can pick through it and it makes a lot more sense.

I have tweaked your example to illustrate what's going on. Consider `test1` and `test2` below:

```py
@tf.function
def test1(a):
    print_op = tf.print(tf.size(a))
    print("python print size: {}".format(tf.size(a)))
    if tf.math.not_equal(tf.size(a),0):
        print('fail')
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
        return None

def test2(a):
    print_op = tf.print(tf.size(a))
    print("python print size: {}".format(tf.size(a)))
    if tf.math.not_equal(tf.size(a),0):
        print('fail')
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
        return None
```

these are identical to one another except for the `@tf.function` decorator.

Now executing `test2(tf.Variable([[]]))` gives us:

```
0
python print size: 0
```

which is the behaviour I assume you'd expect. Whereas `test1(tf.Variable([[]]))` gives:

```
python print size: Tensor("Size_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
fail
0
```

There are a couple of things (beyond the `fail`) about this output that you might find surprising:

- The `print()` statement prints out a (yet to be evaluated) tensor rather than a zero
- The order of the `print()` and the `tf.print()` have been reversed

This is because by adding the `@tf.function` we no longer have a python function but instead have a tf graph mapped from the function code using autograph. This means that, at the point that the `if` condition is evaluated, we have not yet executed `tf.math.not_equal(tf.size(a),0)` and just have an object (an instance of a `Tensor` object) which, in python, is truthy:

```py
class MyClass:
  pass
my_obj = MyClass()
if (my_obj):
  print ("my_obj evaluates to true") ## outputs "my_obj evaluates to true"
```

This means we get to the `print('fail')` statement in `test1` before having evaluated `tf.math.not_equal(tf.size(a),0)`.

So what's the fix?

Well, if we remove the call to the python-only `print()` function in the `if` block and replace it with an autograph-friendly `tf.print()` statement then autograph will seamlessly convert our `if ... else ...` logic to a graph friendly `tf.cond` statement that ensures everything happens in the correct order:

```
def test3(a):
    print_op = tf.print(tf.size(a))
    print("python print size: {}".format(tf.size(a)))
    if tf.math.not_equal(tf.size(a),0):
        tf.print('fail')
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
        return None
```

```py
test3(tf.Variable([[]]))
```

```
0
python print size: 0
```